# Nested Table and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I get all the time an problem with the following snipped from my PL/SQL procedure
I need the variables to create an dynamic SQL statement, but i also need the nested table.

```
 l_code list_code := list_code();

 l_code := PKG_DATA.GET_CODES(in_code) ;


v_sql := 'SELECT ' || in_var_name ||'
              FROM view 
              WHERE supplier = '||in_supplier ||'
                AND factory = '|| in_factory ||'
                AND code IN ('|| ( SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_code) )||')  ';


 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   v_sql
                INTO v_value;
```

v_value is an nested table

> [Error] PLS-00103 (60: 46): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue, [Error] PLS-00103
>   (60: 74): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> , ; for     
>   as group having    intersect minus order start union wh

Does anyone have an idea or an snipped ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v_sql := 'SELECT ' || in_var_name 
       || ' FROM view ' 
       || ' WHERE supplier = :supplier AND factory = :factory ' 
       || '   AND code IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(PKG_DATA.GET_CODES(:code)))';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_value USING in_supplier, in_factory, in_code;
```

Comment: the only mistake in your code is: 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql using in_supplier, in_factory, in_code
                  INTO v_value; ' . Corrected : 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql  INTO v_value using in_supplier, in_factory, in_code; '

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using bind variables

```
v_sql := 'SELECT :in_var_name
          FROM view 
          WHERE supplier = :in_supplier
            AND factory = :in_factory
            AND code IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(:l_code) ))  ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
INTO v_value
USING in_var_name, in_supplier, in_factory, l_code;
```

But chances are, that you don't need dynamic SQL at all:

```
SELECT in_var_name
INTO v_value
FROM view
WHERE supplier = in_supplier
  AND factory = in_factory
  AND code IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_code));
```